# How to make Gmail show date counting backward from today?

Tags: gmail

How to configure Gmail to show date of each email in a format like X days ago rather than the absolute date like Dec 3, 2001

Edit: Although Gmail shows for emails received less than 24 hrs in hrs/min like N min ago, but it doesn't seem to happen for days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With straight-up Gmail, you can't. There are no settings to change the display of the date (outside of the localization you get for your locale).

You would need something like a Userscript to accomplish what you're after.